# why is it impossible to misinterpret a huffman coded message?

Tags: huffman-code

While watching this video on Huffman encoding: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdooBTdW5bM
towards the end the narrator says it's impossible to misinterpret a Huffman coded message when you have the corresponding dictionary, I'd like to know why that is

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy to misinterpret a Huffman coded message. What they mean is that there's no ambiguity; the encoded message and dictionary contain enough information to determine exactly what the original message was.

Comment: Yes. It is easy to misunderstand a lecture, too, and that's not always the lecturer's fault. Sometimes, you just have to try the decode again, paying more attention to the details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the start of the binary string is the start of an encoded letter, and the binary sequence for that letter will allow you to traverse the tree. When you reach a leaf node, you will have interpreted the first letter.

You don't need to know in advance how long that letter is, because you will know when you make it to a leaf. And then you will be at the start of the next letter's binary sequence, and so on. As long as the data and algorithm are correct, you will be able to decode the entire sequence of bits.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#Decompression